# Regex replace in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a string `["BAD":[25.0, 31.0], "GOOD":[33.0, 45.0]]` in which I need to replace the outer square brackets alone with a curly bracket.

The output should look like `{"BAD":[25.0, 31.0], "GOOD":[33.0, 45.0]}`.

Just replace the outer square brackets with curly brackets. The inner square brackets need not be changed.

Comment: How can I replace the above mentioned using regex_replace function in spark scala

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to "replace" it ... just use it. If you have a specific problem, show your code, and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the String is inside a column in a **Spark Data Frame**, right? If it's just a normal Scala String then it would be very easy.

So I will answer in the case it's in a **Spark Data Frame**. The key is to use the right regex pattern to match the outer left and right square bracket

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("DuplicateRemovalExample")
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
// Create original df
val df = Seq("""["BAD":[25.0, 31.0], "GOOD":[33.0, 45.0]]""").toDF("stringColumn")
df.show(false)

//+-----------------------------------------+
//|stringColumn                             |
//+-----------------------------------------+
//|["BAD":[25.0, 31.0], "GOOD":[33.0, 45.0]]|
//+-----------------------------------------+

// Replace the left outer bracket with "^\\[" regex patter, right with "\\]$"
val updatedDF = df.withColumn("updatedColumn1", regexp_replace(col("stringColumn"), "^\\[", "{").cast("string"))
  .withColumn("updatedColumn2", regexp_replace(col("updatedColumn1"), "\\]$", "}").cast("string"))

// Final result
updatedDF.select("updatedColumn2").show(false)
//+-----------------------------------------+
//|updatedColumn2                           |
//+-----------------------------------------+
//|{"BAD":[25.0, 31.0], "GOOD":[33.0, 45.0]}|
//+-----------------------------------------+
```